# Live Data shows previous message on button click

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata

This is ny Repository class:

```
 public LiveData<String> getRegistrationResponse(UserRegistrationModel userRegistrationModel,String headerToken) {


        if (registrationResponseLiveData == null) {
            registrationResponseLiveData = new MutableLiveData();
        }

        ApiServices apiServices = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiServices.class);
        Call<RegisterResponseToken> call = apiServices.userRegistration(userRegistrationModel,headerToken);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<RegisterResponseToken>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RegisterResponseToken> call, Response<RegisterResponseToken> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    responseToken = response.body().getToken();
                    if (responseToken==null){
                        registrationResponseLiveData.postValue("email or number already been taken");

                    }else {
                        registrationResponseLiveData.postValue("Registration Successful");
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RegisterResponseToken> call, Throwable t) {
                registrationResponseLiveData.postValue("Something went wrong");

            }
        });
        return registrationResponseLiveData;


    }
```

this is my ViewModel class:

```
    public LiveData<String> registerUser(UserRegistrationModel registrationData, String headerToken) {
        return registrationRepository.getRegistrationResponse(registrationData,headerToken);
    }
```

and this is my SignUpFragment class code:

```
        myViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
        LiveData<String> sourceLiveData = myViewModel.registerUser(registrationData, BuildConfig.HEADER);

        Observer<String> responseObserver = new Observer<String>() {
            private String previousResponse = null;

            @Override
            public void onChanged(String response) {
                if (response != null) {
                    // Check if the current response is different from the previous one
                    if (!response.equals(previousResponse)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    previousResponse = response;

                    // Remove the observer after showing the Toast
                    sourceLiveData.removeObserver(this);
                }
            }
        };

        sourceLiveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), responseObserver);
```

at first it shows toast multiple time with response message but I have fixed that by removing observer (sourceLiveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), responseObserver);) but now it shows previous response first when clicking on signup button for example first time when I provide name ,phone password and all that it shows me registration successfully, after clicking on very next time with same data it should show phone number exist but it shows previous successful message then clicking on 3rd time it shows "phone already exist" means it behaving like one step previous. Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening because you are trying to handle events with LiveData. LiveData is generally used for observing state changes. To handle events with LiveData, you must reset the state, after handling the event.

So, instead of removing your observer. Try setting the value to null.

```
// instead of this
sourceLiveData.removeObserver(this);

// try setting null, to signal that you have handled the event by showing the toast message
sourceLiveData.postValue(null);
```